# HTML Input type datetime-local setting the wrong time-zone

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, timezone

I've created an app that takes in HTML inputs and goes through JavaScript to create an event on a native calendar events. It takes the time from the `<input type="datetime-local">`, and it's putting in a different time because it's picking a different time zone. If I enter 1 o'clock PM as a time it will return 8 o'clock AM.

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="startDate" name="startDate">
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var startDate = new Date($("#startDate").val());
```

Any help would be awesome. I can post more code if needed.

Comment: Post the full code and make a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @redditor - The question is clear enough.  A fiddle would be useful, but [not every JavaScript question needs a fiddle](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265210/634824).

Comment: @MattJohnson Fair enough. *I* thought it was necessary, which is why *I* requested it. The question was so clear that you edited the question twice /s

Comment: @redditor - Yes, I edited it 3 times actually.  That's because StackOverflow's mission is to create questions and answers that are useful to others.  Reformatting, fixing spelling and tags, and removing unrelated elements are encouraged.  I didn't change the question's intent, nor did I add any qualifying material to the question.  Anyway - asking for a fiddle is fine.  I wasn't trying to scold - just informing you.   Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson I left out the third one because it was just a tagging issue. No worries, buddy, I'll keep a safety lock on my jsfiddle trigger in future :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The HTML5 `datetime-local` input type will give you a *string* value back, which contains the date and time in ISO8601 format, with minute precision, and without any time zone offset.

For example: `2014-07-12T01:00`

The `JavaScript` date object is notoriously inconsistent when it comes to parsing dates from strings.  In most implementations, when you provide a string like this, it erroneously assumes the value is in UTC.  Therefore, the `Date` object you get back will be adjusted by the time zone offset from your local computer.

There are two approaches to work around the problem:

**Option 1**

Manipulate the string to a format that will likely be interpreted as local time by the `Date` object's parser.  Specifically, replace the dashes (`-`) with forward slashes (`/`) and replace the `T` with a space.

```
var s = $("#startDate").val();
var startDate = new Date(s.replace(/-/g,'/').replace('T',' '));
```

**Option 2**

Use a library with more capable date parsing abilities.  There are several available.  One of the most popular is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Moment.js has lots of options, but it just so happens that the default behavior is exactly what you need.  So you can just pass the string to the moment constructor without any parameters.

```
var s = $("#startDate").val();
var startDate = moment(s).toDate();
```

Comment: Okay, i've used the moment.js file and now it is making the event go all day on just the day of the "startDate." I need it to show a specific time and have the endDate close off the event. Any way to do that with the moment? Thank you for the help

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following you.  Please ask this as a new question and provide all of the supporting details.  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870575/using-moment-js-trying-to-create-an-event-in-native-ios-calendar