# Time zone issue in datebox

Tags: jquery-mobile, timezone, datebox

I am having a wierd problem with this code... It is working fine on my PC, but on my iPhone the time is +2 hours... Can someone please have a look at my code example here...

I have been trying for hours to get it working, but everything I try seems to end up in the same way...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Value is right on my PC, but not on my iPhone...?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () { date() }, setInterval(function () { date() }, 1000);
        window.onload = function () { calculateTimlon() }, setInterval(function () { calculateTimlon() }, 1000);

        var secondsDifference;
        var minutesDifference;
        var hoursDifference;
        var totalTimeDifference;
        var startTime;
        var timeRightNow;


        function date() {
            timeRightNow = new Date();

            $('#MyDateInput').datebox({ 'overrideDateFormat': '%A %d-%B-%Y' });
            $('#MyTimeInput').datebox({ 'overrideDateFormat': '%H:%M:%S' });

            startTime = new Date($('#MyDateInput').datebox('callFormat', '%Y-%m-%d', $('#MyDateInput').datebox('getTheDate')) + "T" + $('#MyTimeInput').datebox('callFormat', '%H:%M:%S', $('#MyTimeInput').datebox('getTheDate')));
            totalTimeDifference = Math.abs(new Date(timeRightNow) - new Date(startTime));
            secondsDifference = Math.floor(totalTimeDifference / 1000);
            minutesDifference = Math.floor(secondsDifference / 60);
            secondsDifference = secondsDifference % 60;
            hoursDifference = Math.floor(minutesDifference / 60);
            minutesDifference = minutesDifference % 60;

            $("#hoursValue").html(hoursDifference);
            $("#minutesValue").html(minutesDifference);
            $("#secondsValue").html(secondsDifference);

            $("#MyTimeValue").html(startTime);
            $("#timeRightNowValue").html(timeRightNow);
        }

        function calculateTimlon() {
            var timlon = 100;
            var skatt = 0;
            var semersat = 0;

            var lonForeSkatt = ((semersat / 100) + 1) * timlon;
            var timskatt = (lonForeSkatt * (skatt / 100));
            var lonEfterSkatt = lonForeSkatt - timskatt;

            var minutlonEfterSkatt = lonEfterSkatt / 60;
            var sekundlonEfterSkatt = minutlonEfterSkatt / 60;

            var minutlonForeSkatt = lonForeSkatt / 60;
            var sekundlonForeSkatt = minutlonForeSkatt / 60;

            var sekundCounterEfterSkatt = (sekundlonEfterSkatt * totalTimeDifference) / 1000;
            var krEarnedFromStartEfterSkatt = sekundCounterEfterSkatt.toFixed(2);

            var sekundCounterForeSkatt = (sekundlonForeSkatt * totalTimeDifference) / 1000;
            var krEarnedFromStartForeSkatt = sekundCounterForeSkatt.toFixed(2);


            if (krEarnedFromStartEfterSkatt >= 0) {
                $("#earnedFromStartValue").html(krEarnedFromStartEfterSkatt + "kr");                
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div data-role="page" id="MyPage">

        <div data-role="content" id="MyPageContent" name="MyPageContent" data-position="fixed">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <div id="MyStartTime">
                    <input name="MyDateInput" id="MyDateInput" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "overrideHeaderFormat":"%A %d-%B-%Y","useNewStyle":true, "useFocus":true,"overrideTimeFormat": 24, "closeCallback": "$(\"#MyTimeInput\").datebox(\"open\");"}' />
                    <input name="MyTimeInput" id="MyTimeInput" type="time" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "useNewStyle":true, "useFocus":true,"overrideTimeFormat": 24}' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="timeRightNowText">My choosen startTime: <div id="MyTimeValue"></div></div>

                <div id="hoursText">Hours: <div id="hoursValue"></div></div>
                <div id="minutesText">Minutes: <div id="minutesValue"></div></div>
                <div id="secondsText">Seconds: <div id="secondsValue"></div></div>
                <div id="timeRightNowText">Time right now: <div id="timeRightNowValue"></div></div>

                <div class="ui-block-b" id="valueFromStartTime">This value should start ticking from 0 if the time right now is the same as the time i choose above..<div id="earnedFromStartValue"></div></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Input type datetime-local setting the wrong time-zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703698/html-input-type-datetime-local-setting-the-wrong-time-zone)

Comment: Note, the only difference between this question and the one I linked as duplicate is that you're building the string from datebox controls instead of datetime-local.  The rest of the issue is identical and the same answer applies.

Comment: Did you get it working? An example how I should do would be awesome.

Comment: Read the answer in the question I linked.  In your code, see where you build the `startTime` value by passing the string into the `Date` constructor.

Comment: Actually, reading through [the documentation for this particular control](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/api/events.html), you should be able to retrieve the `Date` object directly. with the `getTheDate` function.  If you need to combine the values from two different boxes (a date box and a time box), then just add their values.  Don't combine them with strings.

Answer (score 0):

I did change my timeRightNow like the example below, and now it's working! It seems like the iPhone needed both the startTime and timeRightNow to look exactly the same way to make the right calculation. I did also add  + "+02:00"  at the end of my startTime, to make the right Time Zone calculation.

```
var datetimeRightNow = new Date();

timeRightNow = new Date(datetimeRightNow.getFullYear() + '-' + (('' + (datetimeRightNow.getMonth() + 1)).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + (datetimeRightNow.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + (('' + datetimeRightNow.getDate()).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + datetimeRightNow.getDate() + "T" + (('' + datetimeRightNow.getHours()).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + datetimeRightNow.getHours() + ":" + (('' + datetimeRightNow.getMinutes()).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + datetimeRightNow.getMinutes() + ":" + (('' + datetimeRightNow.getSeconds()).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + datetimeRightNow.getSeconds() + "+02:00");
```