# Using moment.js trying to create an event in native IOS calendar

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, input, momentjs

I have used the "datetime-local" input to get a start date and an end date from the user to put into the native calendar. This is my code to get and format the "datetime-local":

```
    var s = $("#startDate").val();
    var startDate = moment(s).toDate();
    var e = $("#endDate").val();
    var endDate = moment(s).toDate();
```

This code takes the correct date, but it makes the time set to an all day event. For example, if I put in 1:00 o'clock on 7/21/2014 as the start date and then 1:00 o'clock on 7/22/2014 it will create an all day event on 7/21/2014.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWLkS/)

Comment: If you happen to be using cordova/angular you could use this API to manage your calendar on either ios or android : http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have a typo.  Pass `e` to build the `endDate`, not `s`.

```
var s = $("#startDate").val();
var startDate = moment(s).toDate();
var e = $("#endDate").val();
var endDate = moment(e).toDate(); // <==== this line had used the wrong variable
```

Or, you could instead just call these inline to avoid confusion:

```
var startDate = moment($("#startDate").val()).toDate();
var endDate = moment($("#endDate").val()).toDate();
```

As to why this created an "all day event" - I can't be absolutely certain since I'm not familiar with the particular calendar API you're using.  However, it's possible that since you were sending the same start and end time, that it interpreted that as an all day event.  I believe fixing the typo will solve the issue.

Comment: I changed it and it's still saying it's an all day event. I'll keep checking stuff out. Thanks so much for your help Matt.